# I have battlefield 4 premium for my ps4 but I can't play games like air superiority

Tags: battlefield-4

I've downloaded everything but when I click on anything requiring dlc it says I don't have it.

Comment: have you downloaded and installed china rising from the psn store?  Even if you've paid for it already, you have to manually download it, afaik.

Comment: Well I was going to ask have you tried restarting the game but the date stamp seems to show that you have. I can only hope it has been fixed then.